# Universal-Image-Loader with CircleImageView won't play crossfade animation when drawable set

Tags: android, android-animation, universal-image-loader

I am using [UIL](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)  in order to load contact images. The library works great for the default ImageView.

Recently I made some changes to my app's UI, and I have included circle ImageViews for those said Images. I found this [CircleImageView library](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView) , but the animations I have set to the UIL doesn't seem to play when the image is loaded.

The wiki page of CircleImageView states:

> If you use Picasso for fetching images, you need to set the noFade()
>   option to avoid messed up images. If you want to keep the fadeIn
>   animation, you have to fetch the image into a Target and apply a
>   custom animation when setting it as source for the CircleImageView in
>   onBitmapLoaded().

Anyone know how to do that in UIL?

Feel free to suggest any other circle ImageView libraries if have any to recommend.